# Scipy Stats Wilcoxon X and Y must be one dimensional error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am splitting the 'cnt' variable into two sets based on the value in the 'yr' value so that I can compare the two with a Wilcoxon rank-sum test. I keep getting the error "Samples x and y must be 1-dimensional." Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this? I defined two arrays cnt_yr0 and cnt_yr1 which are 1xn arrays.

```
#Here is some of my code:
from scipy import stats as sc

cnt_yr0 = np.transpose(np.array(data.loc[data['yr']==0,['cnt']]))
cnt_yr1 = np.transpose(np.array(data.loc[data['yr']==1,['cnt']]))
print(cnt_yr0)
print(cnt_yr1)


#binary predictors with continuous response
print(sc.wilcoxon(cnt_yr0,cnt_yr1))

[[16 40 32 ... 52 38 31]]
[[48 93 75 ... 90 61 49]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-16e4c5da6eb0> in <module>
      9 
     10 #binary predictors with continuous response
---> 11 print(sc.wilcoxon(cnt_yr0,cnt_yr1))
     12 print(sc.wilcoxon(np.array(data['holiday']),np.array(data['cnt'])))
     13 print(sc.wilcoxon(np.array(data['workingday']),np.array(data['cnt'])))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\morestats.py in wilcoxon(x, y, zero_method, correction, alternative)
   2844         x, y = map(asarray, (x, y))
   2845         if x.ndim > 1 or y.ndim > 1:
-> 2846             raise ValueError('Samples x and y must be one-dimensional.')
   2847         if len(x) != len(y):
   2848             raise ValueError('The samples x and y must have the same length.')

ValueError: Samples x and y must be one-dimensional.
```

Comment: `[[` means this is a two dimensional array of shape (1,n). You need to convert with indexing or `reshape()` to be one dimensional

Comment: what should I reshape it to?

Answer (score 0):

The array given is 2 dimensional, and the function only accepts one-dimensional arrays

```
np.array([[16, 40, 32, 52, 38, 31]]).shape

(1,6)
```

But you can remove that second dimension with indexing or array.flatten()

```
np.array([[16, 40, 32, 52, 38, 31]])[0,:].shape

(6,)

np.array([[16, 40, 32, 52, 38, 31]]).flatten().shape

(6,)
```

You can also verify with ndim to get the number of dimensions:

```
np.array([[16, 40, 32, 52, 38, 31]]).flatten().ndim

1
```